# Kubernetes Ingress Network Policy is not working on a pod

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-networkpolicy, egress

I created 2 deployments in default namespace

```
/home/asna/YAML::kubectl get pods
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx1-6d7876f5d4-f5xnl   1/1     Running   0          3d6h
nginx2-9498d8f59-jmwpw    1/1     Running   0          3d6h
```

and made their services by exposing them with services name nginx1,nginx2

```
/home/asna/YAML::kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP   3d6h
nginx1       ClusterIP   10.100.126.190   <none>        80/TCP    3d6h
nginx2       ClusterIP   10.105.162.165   <none>        80/TCP    3d6h
```

also i set the label of nginx2 deployment to access=true

```
/home/asna/YAML::kubectl describe pod nginx2-9498d8f59-jmwpw |grep Lab
Labels:           access=true
```

and then created a network policy for nginx1 deployment

```
/home/asna/YAML::kubectl get networkpolicy
NAME                      POD-SELECTOR   AGE
access-nginx              app=nginx1     115m
```

below is the manifest file for network policy

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: access-nginx
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx1
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
    - Egress
  egress:
   - to:
       - podSelector:
           matchLabels:
             access: "true"
  ingress:
   - from:
     - podSelector:
         matchLabels:
           access: "true"
```

according to the above yaml traffic can come to "nginx 1" from the pod with label access=true and recieve traffic from pod labels access=true
but when a request is made from nginx2 to nginx1 it get a success full response

```
root@nginx2-9498d8f59-jmwpw:/# curl nginx1
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

but when a request is made from nginx1 to nginx2 it does not gets anything

```
root@nginx1-6d7876f5d4-f5xnl:/# curl nginx2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nginx2
root@nginx1-6d7876f5d4-f5xnl:/#
```

so i fond a solution on stacoverflow and did this

```
kubectl label namespace kube-system networking/namespace=kube-system
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all-egress
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          networking/namespace: kube-system
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: kube-dns
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 53
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

applied the above yaml for resolving the dns and when i made a request from nginx1 to nginx2 i got a successfull response

```
root@nginx1-6d7876f5d4-f5xnl:/# curl nginx2
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

but after this when i made request from nginx2 to nginx1 i did not got any response

```
root@nginx2-9498d8f59-jmwpw:/# wget --spider --timeout=4 nginx1
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2024-01-29 13:47:49--  http://nginx1/
Resolving nginx1 (nginx1)... 10.100.126.190
Connecting to nginx1 (nginx1)|10.100.126.190|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2024-01-29 13:47:54--  (try: 2)  http://nginx1/
Connecting to nginx1 (nginx1)|10.100.126.190|:80... ^C
root@nginx2-9498d8f59-jmwpw:/#
```

why i am not getting response from nginx1

for more detail output of some commands is given below.

```
/home/asna/YAML::kubectl describe networkpolicy access-nginx
Name:         access-nginx
Namespace:    default
Created on:   2024-01-29 16:45:38 +0500 PKT
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Spec:
  PodSelector:     app=nginx1
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    To Port: <any> (traffic allowed to all ports)
    From:
      PodSelector: access=true
  Allowing egress traffic:
    To Port: <any> (traffic allowed to all ports)
    To:
      PodSelector: access=true
  Policy Types: Ingress, Egress
```

```
/home/asna/YAML::kubectl describe pod nginx1-6d7876f5d4-f5xnl
Name:             nginx1-6d7876f5d4-f5xnl
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             minikube/192.168.49.2
Start Time:       Fri, 26 Jan 2024 11:51:38 +0500
Labels:           app=nginx1
                  pod-template-hash=6d7876f5d4
```

```
/home/asna/YAML::kubectl describe pod nginx2-9498d8f59-jmwpw
Name:             nginx2-9498d8f59-jmwpw
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             minikube/192.168.49.2
Start Time:       Fri, 26 Jan 2024 11:52:14 +0500
Labels:           access=true
```

```
/home/asna/YAML::kubectl describe networkpolicy default-deny-all-egress
Name:         default-deny-all-egress
Namespace:    default
Created on:   2024-01-29 18:45:39 +0500 PKT
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Spec:
  PodSelector:     <none> (Allowing the specific traffic to all pods in this namespace)
  Not affecting ingress traffic
  Allowing egress traffic:
    To Port: 53/TCP
    To Port: 53/UDP
    To:
      NamespaceSelector: networking/namespace=kube-system
      PodSelector: k8s-app=kube-dns
  Policy Types: Egress
```